# Слитно или раздельно пишется слово "сверх/возможности"?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, недопустимая-метка, сложные-слова

Как правильно пишется:
***сверхвозможности*** или ***сверх возможности***?

Comment: Мой юный другъ! И причемъ тутъ "старая орѳографія"? Тэгировать надо съ умомъ.

Comment: @LazyBadger, у вас есть право предлагать правки. исправьте, пожалуйста, то, что считаете неправильным, нажав [edit].

Comment: @alexanderbarakin - я не "считаю неправильным", я задаю уточняющий вопрос, для чего, собственно, и нужны комментарии. Не учите меня, как жить на SE, юноша

Answer (score 5):

**Сверхвозможности** - существительное, в котором приставка "**сверх**-" выражает качественный признак (смысл: особые, чрезвычайно большие и т. п.) но, не обладая формальными признаками прилагательного (полного или краткого) в виде соотв. окончаний, не может трактоваться как отдельная часть речи - поэтому остаётся приставкой и пишется слитно. Аналогично с приставками иноязычного происхождения **"супер-"** и **"экстра-"**.

В выражении **сверх возможности** (**выше** чьих-то сил) "сверх" является предлогом и пишется отдельно от второго слова.

Comment: Только не наречием, а предлогом, а наречием может быть  в таком примере: Это было уже сверх.

Comment: Да, пожалуй (в значении "вне", "за пределами"). Спасибо, поправляю.

Comment: Alex_ander, а в каком толковом словаре есть это слово?

Comment: Я не искал, но в текстах наверняка попадалось.

Comment: Я не про тексты, а про словари. Мне не удалось найти "сверхвозможность" ни в толковых, ни в орфографических словарях, а почему? Как же тогда вы определили  значение слова?

Comment: Я его смысл понимаю по аналогии со "сверхспособностями" (это слово есть в некоторых словарях, напр. - по сетевой наводке - в "Словаре синонимов" Тришина, 2013), как синоним с более широким значением. Оба слова трудно применить в единственном числе.

Answer (score 2):

Нужен контекст.

Тема доклада — возможности и сверхвозможности человека.

Сверх — приставка, с существительными в именительном падеже «сверх» пишется слитно: сверхзвезда, сверхзадача, сверхгигант,  сверхчеловек, сверхкомплект, сверхмодерн, сверхприбыль и сверхприбыли монополий (множественное число, именительный падеж), сверхсрочник, сверхстоимость, сверхзависимость, сверхвозможность.

Это было уже сверх возможности.

Если «сверх» — предлог, то со следующим за ним существительным в родительном падеже слово «сверх» пишется раздельно. Например: сверх (чего?) возможности, сверх (чего?) звезды, сверх лимита, сверх магистрали, сверх договора,  сверх зависимости, сверх норматива, сверх плана, сверх штата, сверх галактики, сверх срока.

Между предлогом и сущ. можно вставить вопрос или определение: сверх всякой возможности.

Answer (score 2):

**1)  СВЕРХВОЗМОЖНОСТИ** (обычно мн.число, И.п. или В.п., подлежащее или дополнение))

Великая Сила используется  для достижения состояний сознания, позволяющих человеческому организму реализовать **свои физические и психические сверхвозможности.**

Многие необычные возможности (или даже **сверхвозможности**! ) станут доступными для вас.

**2) СВЕРХ ВОЗМОЖНОСТИ** (наречное выражение или косвенное дополнение)

― Так, мол, и так! Влюбленный в тебя **сверх возможности**. И ― либо ты сейчас во всем мне покоришься, либо я на сем месте застрелю тебя из пистолета и подожгу фатеру [А. В. Амфитеатров.(из сборника «Бабы и дамы») (1902)]

Не бери на плечи лишней ноши **сверх возможности** снести. [В. Т. Нарежный. Гаркуша, малороссийский разбойник (1825)]

**3) НА СВЕРХВОЗМОЖНОСТИ** (наречное выражение)

Просто люди готовы были умереть, сделать все **на сверхвозможности**.

**Примечание:** слово "сверхвозможность" почему-то **отсутствует в словарях**.

Comment: http://slovar.cc/ses/chudesa/2518490.html

Comment: Меня интересуют обычные словари (Ожегов, Ефремова, Кузнецов, все орфографические словари),  в которых этого слова нет, орфографическая программа его также подчеркивает. Это никого не удивляет?

Comment: Да чему ж удивляться? Слово только входит в общеупотребительную лексику, это термин эзотерики и парапсихологии, как и аффирмация, чакры,астральное тело. Вы же их не ищете в академических толковых словарях? В академическом обществе парапсихология считается псевдонаукой, это сейчас она стала модной, заговорили о сверхвозможностях=сверхспособностях человека. Заговорили-значит, скоро войдёт и в словари.Новые словарные материалы при АН выпускаются ежегодно, видимо, в одном из выпусков сложных слов есть и оно. Процесс словообразования идёт.

Comment: Подчёркивает Ворд, потому что пока в словарях только раздельное написание.

Answer (score 1):

Если это слово имеет право на существование, то, безусловно, пишется слитно. Выражение "сверх возможности" в смысле, предложенном Alex_ander-*ом* и Людмилой, на мой взгляд, звучит не очень по-русски.

***Обновление:***

Поменял своё мнение и убедился на примерах из литературы, что *"сверх возможности"* (в смысле "выше чьих-то сил", как хорошо сказал Alex_ander) действительно употребляется, прочно вошло в язык. Поэтому возражать против него больше не хочу. :)

Comment: Такие комментарии пишутся автоматически после того, как пользователь проделывает некоторые действия, направленные на модерацию контента.

Comment: Аа, я так и подумал, что автоматически, прочитав последний ответ Сержа.

Answer (score 0):

Элемент *сверх* — это приставка, а приставки, как известно пишутся со словами слитно (ещё бы, это ведь морфема слова). В данном случае приставка добавляет значение ***очень большие, пребольшие возможности.***